# How to change SSH ports in Microsoft Azure properly?

Tags: linux, azure, ssh

I have a virtual machine (for testing, not a production server) based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The default SSH port 22 is opened by default on Azure

I want to change it to 12131. I  edited my SSH configuration file and changed port to 12131, then reloaded ssh service by:

```
service ssh reload
```

Then I logged into my Windows Azure portal and updated endpoint SSH as:

**Public Port** 12131

**Private Port** 12131

Now I'm getting timeout with SSH. What is the proper way to change SSH port in Ubuntu 14.04 in Azure?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the most important is the Public port. This is the Internet facing port. You can absolutely safely edit just the public port to XXXX and leave private port to 22. Azure Load Balancer (there is always a Load balancer in front of your VMs in Azure) will properly route the connection to your VM's 22 Port. Thus no need to edit your SSH daemon config.

I suggest that you start over with a new VM and only change the public port of the endpoint. You will not have issues with such configuration.
The issue you faced can be caused by IPTABLES configuration which does not allow incoming 12131.

**Update**

ubussl.cloudapp.net is configured exactly the way I describe. I let it there for test to connect. If you cannot connect, then it is our very own ISP that is blocking this connection. Try shifting the SSH public port to 80 or 443, while living the private to 22 to make sure the connection is not intentionally blocked by ISP / CORP firewall.

Comment: I'm trying again, will update you in a few minutes :)

Comment: I tried again and I just changed public port to 12131 on Ubuntu 14.04 fresh server. I dont think it has iptables activated by default but still i get time out :(

Comment: this is strange. And it works when the public and private ports 22 are?

Comment: Did you find a solution for you problem?

Answer (score -1):

Change **both** the public and the private ports in the Endpoints configuration page to the desired port. [Here I change the ports for SSH from 22 to 993](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTB9O.png)