# Problems changing linux SSH port on Microsoft Azure

Tags: linux, sockets, azure, ssh

I am trying to change the SSH port from 22 on an Ubuntu box hosted on Azure. According this this answer [How to change SSH ports in Microsoft Azure properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183403/how-to-change-ssh-ports-in-microsoft-azure-properly) you can just change the 'public' port while keeping the 'private' ssh port at 22.

However the answer is a bit outdated as there is no mention of public/private ports on Azure as far as I can tell. In the Network Scurity Group settings there are only 'Source port range' and 'Destination port range'.

Using the default settings

```
Source port range: *
Destination port range: 22
```

I can login via shell OK ie

```
ssh -i my_key me@azure_ip
```

When I changed the Source port range to a specific port I want to use as the 'public' ssh port

```
Source port range: new_ip 
Destination port range: 22
```

then try

```
ssh -i my_key me@azure_ip -p new_ip
```

then the connection just times out and I cant connect.

Then I tried changing the Port in the sshd_config on the server, leaving the Source port range as * and changed the Destination port range to the new ip but got a 'public key' error

Any ideas? (I am happy to either change the public port and or the private port)

Comment: For now, when you deploy your VM in ARM module, we can't use NSG to NAT one port to another port. we can change port in sshd_config.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Thanks, anything I have to set on the azure portal if I change the sshd_config apart from the new destination port?

Comment: Please check my answer, we can follow it to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, in ARM module, we can't use NSG to NAT one port to another port.
As a workaround, we can change sshd_config port settings, here are the steps:
1. SSH to this VM, change `sshd_config` settings like this, change port 22 to port 33320:

```
root@jasonvm:~# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 33320
```

2. restart ssh service:

```
root@jasonvm:~# service ssh restart
root@jasonvm:~# netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33320           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33188          52.240.48.24:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:44470          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33320          114.224.98.58:58180     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33186          52.240.48.24:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:22             114.224.98.58:58088     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33182          52.240.48.24:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:44464          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33180          52.240.48.24:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::33320                :::*                    LISTEN
```

3. Add inbound rule to NSG:
[image]

After that completed, we can use new port and public IP address to ssh this VM:

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 33320
```

Comment: A confusing factor was that I had disabled PAM (UsePAM no in sshd_config). Not sure why this should prevent ssh, but have re-set to yes and now ssh on alternate port works as per your setup